# comparing multiple columns between tables hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two tables 
Table A:

```
Fruit       Number
Apple       7235
Plum        1284
Pear        8932
Orange      2839
```

Table B:

```
Fruit       Number
Apple       7235
Apple       3893
Plum        1284
Pear        8932
Orange      2839
Orange      4732
```

I want the end result of my query to get the columns that are not the same for the tables. For example New TableC:

```
Fruit      Number
Apple       3893
Orange      4732
```

I tried to do joins but the join is only taking in the first occurrence of a record. How can i achieve the desired results above.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `full join` which gets you rows missing on either side.

```
select fruit,coalesce(num1,num2) as number
from (select coalesce(a.fruit,b.fruit) as fruit,a.number as num1,b.number as num2
      from a 
      full join b on a.fruit=b.fruit and a.number=b.number
      where a.number is null or b.number is null
     ) t
```